# Vibration not working on my android device

Tags: vibration

Vibration not working in my android device. I am currently running on android version 4.2 Jelly Bean. My phone model is Lenovo a369i.

Comment: Hi, can you explain exactly what do you trying to do? It just does not work, event for system notifications? Or just for your app?

Comment: It's not working for everything. Phone calls not vibrating, when putting in meeting mode its not vibrating. Also I checked the vibration test but its also not working. Please help

Comment: if test does not work too, the vibrator is broken, it's hardware problem...

Comment: Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: err, it is material problem... Buy a new phone...

Comment: Well i seems funny but i banged my phone for 2-3 times(top part where vibrator lies) on floor and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable with the disassembly of the devices, you might want to give a look at your vibration module. It might be possible that it is stuck or 
oxidized.